# Longtable: Vertical Line not complete

Tags: tables, longtable, line, vertical

I am using the `longtable` LaTeX package to create a multi-page table with three columns, one of which contains only images. However, the vertical line between the middle and right column does not complete up to the top `\hline` as seen in the screenshot. [image: Screenshot of error]

This is the code I'm using to create the table. I removed most of the lines to make it viable easier because it's basically the same line repeated over.

```
\begin{longtable}{m{0.5\textwidth}|m{0.25\textwidth}|m{0.15\textwidth}}
Thumbnail & Description & Number of Images \\
\hline \\
\endhead

\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{img/data/some_img1.png} & Description 1 & 2 \\
\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{img/data/some_img2.png} & Description 2 &  10 \\

\caption{Gathered Data}
\label{tbl:some_data_table}\\
\end{longtable}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Remove `\\ ` after first `\hline`.

Answer (score 1):

As [Zarko already mentioned in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/501780/longtable-vertical-line-not-complete#comment1267353_501780), you can get rid of the undesired gap in the vertical line by removing the `\\` after `\hline`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}


\begin{longtable}{m{0.5\textwidth}|m{0.25\textwidth}|m{0.15\textwidth}}
Thumbnail & Description & Number of Images \\
\hline 
\endhead

\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image} & Description 1 & 2 \\
\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image} & Description 2 &  10 \\

\caption{Gathered Data}
\label{tbl:some_data_table}\\
\end{longtable}


\end{document}
```

---

As you can see, removing the `\\` also removed the small vertical whie space between the `\hline` and the first image. If you want to keep such a space around the images, I'd sugggest the usage of the `cellspace` package. In teh following MWE, I have also used the `xltabular` package in order to make the table as wide as the textwidth without the need to calculate the required column widths manually. I have also added the `adjustbox` package in order to use the `valing` option. Lastly, I have also moved the `\caption` to the top of the table as it might be a good idea to inform the reader what the table is about before starting the actual table. Especially if your table is longer than one page.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}


\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{\tabcolsep}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{\tabcolsep}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}


\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{Sc|X|l}
\caption{Gathered Data}\label{tbl:some_data_table}\\
\makecell[l]{Thumbnail} & Description & \makecell[l]{Number of\\ Images} \\
\hline
\endhead

\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth,valign=c]{example-image} & Description 1 & 2 \\
\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth,valign=c]{example-image} & Description 2 &  10 \\
\end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```

---

Personally, I'd also remove the vertical lines entirely and use horizontal lines from the `booktabs` package. I would also top align the contents of the cells:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}


\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{\tabcolsep}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{\tabcolsep}
\usepackage{makecell}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}


\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{}ScXl}
\caption{Gathered Data}\label{tbl:some_data_table}\\
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Thumbnail} & Description & \makecell[l]{Number of\\ Images} \\
\midrule
\endhead
\bottomrule
\endfoot

\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth,valign=t]{example-image} & Description 1 & 2 \\
\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth,valign=t]{example-image} & Description 2 &  10 \\
\end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```